# Prove that the function $f$ is injective

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Define a function: $\mathbb N \times \mathbb N \to \mathbb Q$:
$$f((a,b)) = a + \frac{1}{b}.$$

Choose $(a,b) \in \mathbb{N}, \ (c,d) \in \mathbb{N}$

workings:

$$ 
f((a,b)) = a + \frac{1}{b} \\
f((c,d)) = c + \frac{1}{d} \\
$$

Suppose that $f((a,b)) = f((c,d))$:

$$
a + \frac{1}{b} = c + \frac{1}{d} \\
d(ab+1) = b(cd+1).
$$

How do I make $a = c$ and $b = d$ ?

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Let's start small, shall we? What is the definition of injectivity?

Comment: if $f(a) = f(b) $, then a = b

Comment: Hint: what is the largest natural number that is strictly smaller than $a+\frac{1}{b}$?

Comment: Maybe try a special case first.  Suppose the value is an integer, so $f(a,b)=n\in \mathbb N$.  What are $a,b$ in terms of $n$?

Answer (score 2):

If (for instance) $b=1$ then $d=1$ because $1/d\in\Bbb N$ etc (id. if $d=1$)

If $b,d\neq1$ then $a=c=\lfloor f(a,b)\rfloor$ etc

Answer (score 1):

Alternate (not as good as the other answer) approach:
$\gcd(d,cd+1) = \gcd(b,ab+1) = 1$.

**Lemma:** If $\gcd(x,y) = \gcd(a,b) = 1$ and $ax = by$ then $a=y, b = x$ (For $x,y,a,b$ positive integers). 
**Proof:** $ax = by \implies a \mid by \overset{Euclid}{\implies } a\mid y$ and $ax = by \implies y \mid ax \overset{Euclid}{\implies} y \mid a  \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \blacksquare$

Then, we easily have $b=d$ and the rest follows.

Comment: It is worthwhile to show an approach that continues from where OP left off and how we can push through to close the gap.

Comment: @CalvinLin While typing the answer, I was actually going for the above, but I got sniped, so switched the approach :)

Answer (score 0):

Since $b\ge 1$ we have $a<a+\frac{1}{b}\le a+1$. Then from $a + \frac{1}{b} = c + \frac{1}{d}$ we get $a=\left\lceil a + \frac{1}{b}\right\rceil=\left\lceil c + \frac{1}{d}\right\rceil=c$.